# Understanding the "long division" notation used in Heath's commentary on Euclid Book 7 Proposition 2

Tags: elementary-number-theory, euclidean-geometry, math-history

Heath's commentary on proposition 2 of book 7 of the Elements uses some notation I'm not familiar with, as shown in the image below. I wonder if someone could show the "long division" in a modern form please?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Perhaps you could explain your own favorite long division notation first? From my own experience with students, there are still multiple notations for long division that are taught around the world.

Comment: 1. $a$ divided by $b$ gives $p$ as quotient, and $c=a-pb$ as remainder. 2. $b$ divided by $c$ gives $q$ as quotient, and $d=b-qc$ as remainder. And so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation denotes this $\ \begin{align} 
\color{#c00}{b}\,)\,&\color{#c00}a\,(\,p\\
      &\underline{\!pb}\\
      &\color{#c00}c
\end{align}\!\!\iff$ $ \begin{align}a\,\div\, b &\,=\, p\\ {\rm and}\   & \\  a-pb &:=\, c \end{align}\!\!\iff$ $ \, \color{#c00}a\bmod\color{#c00}b\, =\, \color{#c00}c$

So the notation pictured below denotes the Euclidean algorithm computation below

$$\begin{align} a\bmod b = c,&\ \ b\bmod c = d,\ \  c\bmod d= 0\\[.3em]
 {\rm so}\,\ \ \gcd(a,b) \ \,=\,\  \gcd(b,c)& \ \,=\,\  \gcd(c,d)\ \,=\,\ \gcd(d,0)=d \end{align}\qquad$$

|  |
| --- |
| [image] |

Answer (score 2):

[image: graphic]

Commentary is:
Divide $a$ by $b$;  quotient is $p$.
multiply $p$ times $b$, subtract that from $a$, get remainder $c$.
Then do it again, the former divisor $b$ is divided by the remainder $c$.
Repeat until one of the divisions comes out even.

Example.

Find GCD of $8$ and $26$.

```
8 ) 26 ( 3
    24
    ——
     2 ) 8 ( 4
         8
         —
```

Division comes out even, we are finished, our GCD is the last divisor, $2$.